# Will Office 2013 64bit work alongside Visio 2010 64bit?

Tags: microsoft-office, upgrade, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-visio, microsoft-office-2013

I currently have office 64bit 2010 installed + Visio 64bit 2010.
I just bought office 2013 64bit proplus. Can I upgrade office 2010 to office 2013 and keep Visio 2010. Will office 2013 64bit+ Visio 64bit 2010 work? or I will loose the ability to use Visio 2010 if I upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Visio is a separate product to Office, so yes, it will work side-by-side.